# My C++ Power Calculation is not outputing the calculation

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to take two numbers (a base and an exponent) and calculate the power. For example, base 5 to the power of 2 should equal 25. But when I input these two numbers, it won't output the result. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

double power(double base, int exponent) //declaring and defining
{
    double result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i = exponent; i++) // @suppress("Assignment in condition")
    {
        result = result + base;
    }
    return result;
}


void print_pow(double base, int exponent)
{

    double myPower = power(base, exponent);
    cout << base << " raised to the " << exponent  << " power is " << myPower << endl;
}

int main()
{
    double base;
    int exponent;
    cout << "What is the base? ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "What is the exponent? ";
    cin >> exponent;
    print_pow(base, exponent);
}

Console:

What is the base? 5`
What is the exponent? 2
```

After entering these two numbers, it is missing the answer. It is just a blank line on my console.

Comment: The comments in your code state the problem clearly 
`// @suppress("Assignment in condition")`.

Your program is stuck in an infinite loop in `for(int i = 0; i = exponent; i++)`

Comment: Power calculation by addition?! Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `power()` function has two issues. First of all, the condition in the for loop is wrong (it's `i = exponent`, which is an assignment, when it should be `i < exponent`). Secondly, the expression should be `result = result * base` to get the desired result.

```cpp
double power(double base, int exponent) //declaring and defining
{
    double result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change:

```
for(int i = 0; i = exponent; i++)// @suppress("Assignment in condition")
```

To:

```
for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
```

And also the calculation line in the loop should feature multiplication:

```
result = result * base;
```

Why do you import cmath and then calculate power in a loop (very inefficient way)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is already stated in comment by @Yaroslav Fyodorov but the solution could be as simple as using standard function:

```
double myPower = std::pow(base, exponent);
```

Your power() implementation is not necessary at all.

Comment: It's OP's wish to use standard library function or not, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AkibAzmain Thanks for the guideline. I am new to stack overflow. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: On Eclipse, pow never works. It always gives me an error

Answer (score -2):

the power function should be
`

```
double power(int base, int exponent) 
{
    double result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) 
    {
          result *=  base;
    }
    double result;
}`
```

Comment: There is no `=*` -operator in C++ (actually that's assignment followed by value-of), did you mean `*=`?

Comment: @churill For fun, there _was_ a `=*` in C (pre-C89), meant the same as `*=`.

Comment: Amr Khaled, `base` is not used in `power(int base, int exponent)`.  Code needs review.

Comment: `result` will only always be 1 in your function. Don't forget to test before posting!

Comment: If `result` equals to zero and `result *= result` is executed in an infinite loop and if that loop ever ends, `result` will still equal to zero.